# messed up confused dns records!

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, cname-record, mx-record, dkim

I'm totally new to this, please help. While trying to redirect the mail from my server to gmail using MX records, I think I've messed up, and I'm way confused about that.

First: I can set DNS records both in DomainCentral (registrar) and in cPanel (server). I don't know where the changes should be done. Should I remove all records from cPanel?

Second: I changed CNAME in DomainCentral like this: mail -> ghs.google.com for many hours now. And removed CNAME entries in cPanel. mail.mydomain.com doesn't work.

Third: removed mx.mydomain.com and added the following to DomainCentral:

```
1   @       ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
5   @       ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
5   @       ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.
10  @       ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
10  @       ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.
```

it doesn't work.

Fourth: DKIM setup requires two fields to be filled in, and DomainCentral offers one field for TXT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your DNS should be changed with your DNS provider. This might be the same as your registrar, or it could be in your cpanel. We can't answer that one for you, but my money is on CPanel. If your registrar has "nameserver" records, *do not touch these*.
2. Did you put a full stop `.` at the end of `ghs.google.com`? You've done it correctly in step #3. DNS propogation can take time though, so if it's taking a while, it depends on what the TTL (Time To Live) of the previous record was. Hours is often not enough time to wait. Sometimes it takes days.
3. See above. DNS propogation takes time, especially if the upstream DNS servers are badly behaved (smack, bad DNS). What you've got there looks totally correct though.
4. You'll need to contact DomainCentral's support and ask them for additional TXT records. Although to be honest from what I've read in the past, you're lucky to even have one.

If you're really serious about it, you might want to consider seperating your DNS from your hosting provider. This gives you the ability to dump your host without having to re-configure all your DNS, and also means that you can guarantee that your DNS settings are correct, without having to guess where you're meant to go to get it work.

-- Update --

I've done an `nslookup` on your domain, and the MX records look totally correct:

```
> set q=mx
> christian-linux.com
Server:  enetsdc1.enets.local
Address:  192.168.161.2

Non-authoritative answer:
christian-linux.com     MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = aspmx3.googlemail.com
christian-linux.com     MX preference = 1, mail exchanger = aspmx.l.google.com
christian-linux.com     MX preference = 5, mail exchanger = alt1.aspmx.l.google.com
christian-linux.com     MX preference = 5, mail exchanger = alt2.aspmx.l.google.com
christian-linux.com     MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = aspmx2.googlemail.com

aspmx3.googlemail.com   internet address = 72.14.213.27
aspmx2.googlemail.com   internet address = 74.125.43.27
```

That all looks correct, so I'd say it's just a propogation thing.

Comment: @Mark Thanks for your reply! Can I get a little more of help?

**1.** I had a look a bit further in cPanel, and it allows for the modification of A, CNAME, and TXT only, sorry! I could get my web site running by actually changing "nameservers" in DomainCentral to point to the webhoster. I don't whether it was right and who is my DNS provider... _I want to use Cloudflare also._

**2.** DomainCentral removes all dots at the end. Looking at who.is, A and MX TTLs are 4 hours, NS and SOA 1 day, and don't know about CNAME.

**3.** It's four hours from what I understood, so i think I did it wrong.

Comment: @Teresa - whatever your "nameservers" are pointing to, they're your DNS provider. Just because the TTL is 4 hours, doesn't mean that it's going to take 4 hours to change. There are a lot of mis-behaved DNS cachers out there. If you're willing to post your real domain name, people will be happy to do an `nslookup` from our end to see if we can spot anything obvious.

Comment: @Mark christian-linux.com

Comment: @Mark CNAME worked instantly in cPanel, thanks. MX seems a bit complicated yet.

Comment: @Teresa - I've updated my answer

Comment: @Mark Yes, you suggested I should do in cPanel (my DNS provider), so I googled why I couldn't change MX in cPanel. It is available under Mail settings, and not under DNS settings! It worked in the last minute!

Comment: Ahh, righto! Glad you got it sorted.